# What is the error in my python code

Tags: python-2.7

You are given an integer NN on one line. The next line contains NN space separated integers. Create a tuple of those NN integers. Let's call it TT. 
Compute `hash(T)` and print it.

Note: Here, `hash()` is one of the functions in the `__builtins__` module.

Input Format 
The first line contains NN. The next line contains NN space separated integers.

Output Format 
Print the computed value.

Sample Input

2

1 2

Sample Output

3713081631934410656

My code

```
a=int(raw_input())
b=()
i=0
for i in range (0,a):
    x=int(raw_input())
    c = b + (x,) 
    i=i+1

hash(b)
```

> Error:
>   invalid literal for int() with base 10: '1 2'

Comment: Your code isn't pasted properly. Please fix the indentation.

Answer (score 1):

There are three errors that I can spot:
First, your for-loop is not indented.
Second, you should not be adding 1 to i - the for-loop does this automatically.
Thirds - and this is where the error is thrown - is that `raw_input` reads the entire line. If you are reading the line '1 2', you cannot convert this to an int.

To fix this problem, I suggest doing:

```
line = tuple(map(int,raw_input().split(' ')))
```

This takes the raw input, splits it into an list, makes this list into ints, then turns this list into a tuple.

In fact, you can scrap the entire for loop. You could answer this problem in two lines of code:

```
raw_input()#To get rid of the first line, which we do not need
print hash(tuple(map(int,raw_input().split(' '))))
```

Comment: My for loop is indented. I pasted it here in a wrong way. Y should I use split. i will always give a integer as input. Why can't I initialize a using just raw_input

Answer (score 0):

The input format

> next line contains NN space separated integers

eg: `1 2 3`, is not an integer (because of the spaces), that is why when you try `int(raw_input())` your code throws an error. You should use `split(' ')` as the other answer has suggested, to separate each integer. This will remove the error.

Also, there is no need to use `i=i+1` as the loop will take care of it

Comment: Y would i input an integer using spaces and use split. I will directly input an integer

Comment: You said that the second line of your input is `NN space separated integers`. So when you do a raw_input(), it takes all those integers, but you cannot process them altogether, that is why you need to split them and then use

Answer (score 0):

Try the below code:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    n = int(input())
    integer_list = map(int, input().split())
    t = tuple(integer_list)
    print(hash(t))
```

Answer (score -1):

Try This code for Python-3

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    n = int(input())
    integer_list = map(int, input().split())

input_list = [int(x) for x in integer_list]
t = tuple(input_list)``
print(hash(t))
```